# Blink value for 5 seconds then stop when the value change ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am making a counter that each time the value change it will blink for 5 seconds then stop ..

example. the value is "5" so when it change to "6" it will blink for 5 seconds and it will blink again if the value change to 7.

sds.php

```
<?php
include("db.php");

$test = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM office WHERE office_desc = 'SDS'");
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($test);
    $counter = $row['counter'];

echo $counter;
?>
```

viewer.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
    {
    $('#load_count1').load('sds.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 1000); 
</script>

<div id='load_count1'></div>  <---- blink
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a way to persist the previous value. then you must compare if the previous value is equal to the new value if so, run the function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      let previousValue = 0;
      var auto_refresh = setInterval(
      function ()
      {
        const currentValue = 'pull value' // need to pull the value from your backend
        if(currentValue != previousValue){
            //run here the blink
        }

      }, 1000);
      previousValue = currentValue; // make the previues value equal to current value
</script>

<div id='load_count1'></div>  <---- blink
```